# How do I change the size of specific named items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I have been working on a texture pack that has items in it, where if I rename my item it changes texture. The base item is 16x16 but the named version is 32x32. If anyone can help, I know about .json files but don't know the codes. I found a code but I don't know how to make it on only 1 file that only changes when named.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You should add that code to your question if you know it's useful.